# How to hide the grid lines of a DataGridView? Winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms

How to hide the grid lines of a DataGridView?

I have searched the internet but found no solutions on this.
Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can try

`MyGrid.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.None;`

Answer (score 9):

```
dataGridView1.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.None;
```

Answer (score 4):

You Can Also Set this in DataGridView Properties,

Select DataGridView --> Properties --> CellBorderStyle change this to None.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this one

```
this.dataGridView1.AdvancedCellBorderStyle.All = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TableView view = new TableView();
view.HorizontalGridLineThickness = 1;
view.VerticalGridLineThickness = 1;
view.HorizontalGridLineBrush = Brushes.Orange;
view.VerticalGridLineBrush = Brushes.Orange;
dataGridControl.View = view;
```

try this code.....its very useful #Gawtam

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.