# Hide DataGridView gridlines

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, .net-2.0

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825710/how-to-hide-the-grid-lines-of-a-datagridview-winforms-c-sharp) question, and have set `CellBorderStyle` to `None`, but for some reason I am still getting gridlines on my `DataGridView`:

[image]

This is the code I am using to initialize my control:

```
public FtpTransferGridView()
{
    this.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    this.ReadOnly = true;
    this.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    this.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
    this.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
    this.ShowEditingIcon = false;
    this.RowHeadersVisible = false;
    this.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
    this.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(240, 240, 225);
    this.RowTemplate.Height = 20;
    this.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.None;
    this.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window;

    InitializeColumns();
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you try `dataGridView1.AdvancedCellBorderStyle.All = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;`

Comment: @V4Vendetta Yes I did, that did not help. See my answer for what was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was related to the custom painted progress column cells.

In it's cell paint method I had code similar to:

```
base.Paint(g, ...);
g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
if (value <= 0) return;

//paint the progress bar

g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;
```

The error would happen when the method would exit without painting the progress bar, leaving the graphics smoothing mode in an incorrect state.

Settings the `SmoothingMode` of the `Graphics` only after the `value <= 0` check solves the problem:

```
base.Paint(g, ...);
if (value <= 0) return;
g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

//paint the progress bar

g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;
```

Comment: i guess you should also post the relevant paint logic as part of the question since it ain't inferred.

Comment: @V4Vendetta The paint logic has no relevance to the issue. The issue is that the `SmoothingMode` was left on `HighQuality` when the method finished, and was used by the system for the painting of other cells and their borders, which apparently caused gridlines to be painted.